# RSpec stopped working after upgrading to OSX Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rspec, osx-lion

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
```

Does anyone have a solution? Would upgrading Xcode to 4.1 help?

Comment: I'm not using RSpec for testing, but updating (other rather installing Xcode 4.1 - Lion removed my Xcode 4.0) helped me a lot to install various gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/opt/local/bin/identify` is probably [ImageMagick’s *identify*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php).

You probably need to rebuild your installation of ImageMagick. Based on the pathname (`/opt/local/`), you probably installed it as a part of MacPorts.

You should probably follow the instructions for [*Migrating a MacPorts install to a new major OS version or CPU architecture*](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration): install new Xcode, install latest MacPorts base, record installed ports, remove ports, reinstall ports.

Unfortunately, [MacPorts’ bug #30322](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30322) indicates that the ImageMagick port may not yet build properly under Lion (found via [MacPorts’ *Lion Problems* page](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/LionProblems)).

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend installing the latest XCode, 4.1, from the App Store before you do anything else, so as to get the latest build tools and dev libraries.

You'll likely need to recompile any Gems with native bindings (which it looks like you have, since something is looking for OpenCL, likely not RSPec itself).

To recompile all your gems run:

```
gem pristine --all
```

`dydl` errors are commonly associated with database drivers/bindings. Try re-installing your database if neither of the above work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to this after a clean install of Lion, with Xcode 4.1 installed (both from the Mac App Store).

What eventually fixed it was running `sudo gem install rspec -v 2.6.0`. The actual problem (for me, your mileage may vary) was that the script stub wasn't being installed in `/usr/bin`, which meant the OS couldn't find RSpec without a full path spec.