# Will upgrading to OSX Lion affect my current rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-lion

I'm thinking of upgrading to OSX Lion. The only thing is, I don't want to lose my current rails environment and setup so I am wondering if upgrading to Lion is going to give me any problems? Has anyone else experienced any problems with the upgrade to their dev environment (i.e. databases, rvm, paths etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people I know had some minor issues, but in the end thinks tend to work out. Some reading:

- [Upgrading to Lion](http://www.ror-e.com/posts/15)
- [Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)
- [RSpec stopped working after upgrading to OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773128/rspec-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-osx-lion)

To sum it up, yes you'll likely have issues, but there shouldn't be any show stoppers. Just set aside a couple of hours and fix everything in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I installed lion and a number of things were giving me fits.  (Couldn't find things like ruby.h, bundle install fails, etc)

Next I downloaded Xcode 4.1 (free with Lion) and the app store claimed it was installed.

At a shell prompt I ran "xcodebuild -version" and got a command not found.  Clearly Xcode was not installed.

So I used spotlight (shortcut - command space bar) to search the mac for "Xcode install" and ran that to install Xcode 4.1

"xcodebuild -version" now worked and so far all other issues are resolved.